# Having issues with portfowarding on my router, out of ideas

Tags: port-forwarding, port, minecraft

Recently I have been trying to portfoward a minecraft server, a couple of months ago I could do it like no problem. But lately I've been having issues. I'm trying to port forward port 25565 (default for minecraft). I went into firewall and made some inbound and outbound rules to allow the port through. I port forward it on my HG8245W5. Here is my port mapping,

[image: Port mapping table]

Can you see if I'm doing anything wrong? Also here is my config file and firewall

[image: Minecraft configuration]
[image: Windows firewall settings]

The 192.168.100.2 is my ipv4.

Comment: Ayy i got it to work, it was something to do with DMZ settings

Comment: Do not DMZ your computer. This opens it to attacks from the internet. Better do the port-forwarding right.